# Select duplicate values from a list

Tags: list-manipulation

How can I select the duplicate values in a list?

Example:

```
{1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1}
```

Comment: I need to return the duplicate values.

Comment: So in your example what do you need to return?

Comment: I need to return {1}

Comment: Have you even looked at the link above? It returns `{1}`. Please make an effort.

Comment: @Öskå, I am so  sorry! thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want all duplicates then:

```
list = {1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1}

Select[Split@Sort@list, Length@# > 1 &]
```

if you want one from each duplicate then

```
Select[Split@Sort@list, Length@# > 1 &][[;;,1]]
```